# What to do when more than one close reason applies

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I frequently come across questions in the Close Vote Review where it seems that more than one, if not several close reasons apply. I'm wondering if there is a prescribed method for addressing these; which close reasons should take precedence?

Simply put: If a question is asked that is unclear, too broad, off-topic because they haven't included valid code to reproduce their issue, and off-topic because they haven't demonstrated an understanding of the problem being solved what is the correct response?

Comment: @Bart I was curios because questions that are put "on hold" or closed list the close reason partially as corrective guidance to the OP, if only one of many issues is given doesn't that leave the OP with the impression that they only need to fix the reason given

Comment: There's also: [Voting to close: dupe vs “off topic” / minimal understanding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193377/voting-to-close-dupe-vs-off-topic-minimal-understanding)

Comment: @chuex that's a much better fit thanks

Comment: Sometimes I think we could use an "all of the above" close reason